# Можно заменить append() что нибудь чтобы заменилось?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Можно заменить `append()` что нибудь чтобы заменилось? Я сделал такой код хорошо работает но бывает так. Который добавляется каждый наведении курсора. Как сделать чтобы только 1 раз добавить и патом заменить или ваше удалить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter','[tooltip]', function(){
        $(this).append("<tooltip></tooltip>");
        $(this).find('tooltip').empty().append($(this).attr('tooltip'));
    });
});
```

```css
[tooltip] {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
[tooltip]:hover tooltip {
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
}
[tooltip] tooltip {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #34495E;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: attr(tooltip);
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: none;
}
[tooltip] tooltip:after{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #34495E transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
}
[tooltip] tooltip:before{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.div {
  margin: 50px 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" tooltip="Я плавающая подсказка">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - просто проверить добавлен уже тултип или нет

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter','[tooltip]', function(){
        var tooltip = $(this).find('tooltip');
        if(tooltip.length !== 0)
          tooltip.html($(this).attr('tooltip'));
        else
          $(this).append("<tooltip>"+$(this).attr('tooltip')+"</tooltip>");
    });
});
```

```css
[tooltip] {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
[tooltip]:hover tooltip {
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
}
[tooltip] tooltip {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #34495E;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: attr(tooltip);
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: none;
}
[tooltip] tooltip:after{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #34495E transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
}
[tooltip] tooltip:before{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.div {
  margin: 50px 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" tooltip="Я плавающая подсказка">Text</div>
```